# NSFastEnumerationIteration.member Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, nsfastenumeration

I have some difficult to convert my Swift 2.2 app to Swift 3.0.
I have some errors and I don't find the solution yet. Currently, my worst problem is with `NSFastEnumerationIteration`, I try to get records from JSON but with this error I can't. This is the screenshot of my code with the problem :

[image: Swift 3.0 error with NSFastEnumerationInteration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 you need to specify the type of object,so specify the type of your data Array to `[[String:Any]]`.

```
if let dataArr = data as? [[String: Any]] {
    for dd in dataArr {
        //your code for accessing dd.
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

**For in** **loop** only knows that your **variable** **data** is an array and doesn't know anything else, so you need to provide as well **the type of the content** of your **variable data**:

```
let dataToParse = dataweneed.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
let jsonOptions = [JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers]
let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataToParse, options: jsonOptions)

// now For in loop would know that you
// could have an array of dictionaries
if let data = data as? [[String: Any]] {
  for dd in data {
    // your code
  }
}
```